# How to modify the last value of a for loop via querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Within my following setup I can easily manage all of my `.faq-content` items by modifying their class values via classList (shown below).  But what if I "also" want to modify the very last ".faq-content" item by adding an "additional" class to it?  How can I further my understanding in manipulating my values?  Can I do it all within this one for loop?

```js
    var mBundle = document.querySelectorAll('.faq-bundle .faq-content');
    for (var i = 0, len = mBundle.length; i < len; i++) {
        mBundle.[i].classList.add("max-height-zero");
        mBundle.[i].classList.add("hide-height");
    }
```

Comment: You mean like `mBundle[mBundle.length-1].classList.add('last-item')` (obviously not in the loop, but before or after)?

Comment: Yes. just learning the proper way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of a loop you can check the counter if it reached the last item:

```
if (i == len - 1)
  mBundle[i].classList.add("blah");
```

Or

anytime else:

```
mBundle[mBundle.length-1].classList.add("blah");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use all these Elements lenght - 1

```js
const b = document.querySelectorAll(".b")

b[b.length - 1].style.background = "red"
```

```css
.b{
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```